# Try-catch em loop causando erro

Tags: javascript, loop, while, try-catch

Estou com o seguinte código, que tenta clicar em um botão após 60 segundos, e caso o mesmo não tenha carregado, tenta novamente após 60 segundos.

```js
    while(true) {
      var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        try{
          document.querySelector('.department-info').click()
        } catch(e) {
          console.log('Retrying in 60 seconds...') //error handling
        }
      }, 60000)
    };
```

O problema é que ele não está entrando no `catch()` e está, após algumas execuções do laço, fazendo a página travar e fechar. Podem me ajudar? O que está sendo feito errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use while para isso, use uma função. O while é assíncrono com o setTimeout e irá gerar um gargalo de processos, causando o travamento. Usando uma função você consegue fazer de forma sincronizada, só chamando o setTimeout novamente após o tempo definido:

```
(function checa(){
   setTimeout(function() {
     try{
       document.querySelector('.department-info').click()
     } catch(e) {
       console.log('Retrying in 60 seconds...') //error handling
       checa(); // chama novamente a função após o tempo
     }
   }, 60000)
})(); // função auto-executada
```

**Teste de 2 segundos:**

Ao clicar no `body`, irá inserir o botão com a classe `.department-info` e disparar o click :

```js
$("body").click(function(){
   $(this).html('<button class="department-info" onclick="alert(\'Clicado\')">OK</button>')
});

(function checa(){
   setTimeout(function() {
     try{
       document.querySelector('.department-info').click()
     } catch(e) {
       console.log('Retrying in 2 seconds...') //error handling
       checa();
     }
   }, 2000)
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique aqui para adicionar o botão
```